# How do I append a baseurl to this in JSON?

Tags: jquery, json, dom

```
window.location = "../employer/dashboard"
```

Need to append a base url so I wont have to add ../

Answer (score 1):

you might wanna check [window.location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) and all it's properties, especially `window.location.hostname`

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick (untested), but seems easy enough.

var root = location.protocol + "://" + location.host + ":" + location.port;

Comment: You are missing the colon after the protocol and a (non-standard) port.